# What is the recommended method of handling multiple Task orchestration if one or more tasks needs to be triggered conditionally

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am looking to verify my approach below to see if there is a better way to handle the scenario.

[Scenario]
I have a requirement to run few expensive operations to validate couple of input parameter that I receive as part of my payload. validation of each of these parameters can be done independently, and so I am looking to execute them simultaneously and then orchestrate the completion using Task.WhenAll() method to proceed once the validation is complete.

I am looking for an optimal way to solve for this. If there is a design pattern that handles this scenario better, please do advise.

The code below simulates this operation. I have 2 methods that are invoked to validate paramA and paramB. paramA is only validated is the attribute validateParamA is set to true. I want to capture the result of both the backend operation in val1 (result of ValidateParamA) and val2 (result of ValidateParamB) respectively. Note, the sleeydelay I have specified for both operations is **random**.

The code below also shows the solution I have written. However, I am not convinced this is the optimal solution in this scenario. Reason for my doubt are :

1. There are too many Tasks being spun up for orchestration.
2. The code structure is very convoluted; there is Task being triggered to assign value and that assignment task in then itself converted to a Task for orchestration.

I appreciate any guidance on a more optimal solution.

```
class Foo
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        bool validateParamA = true;
        var myFoo = new Foo();
        bool val1 = false, val2 = false;
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        if (validateParamA)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(
                async () =>
                {
                    val1 = await myFoo.ValidateParamA(50);
                }
            ));
        }
        
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(
            async () =>
            {
                val2 = await myFoo.ValidateParamB(30);
            }
        ));

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        Console.WriteLine(val1);
        Console.WriteLine(val2);
    }

    public async Task<bool> ValidateParamA(int sleepdelay)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(sleepdelay);
        return true;
    }
    
    public async Task<bool> ValidateParamB(int sleepdelay)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(sleepdelay);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you get a compilation warning in `ValidateParamA` and `ValidateParamB` methods, about an `async` method that lacks `await`?

Comment: @theodor-zoulias I do get a validation warning, but not a compile time error. The method executes synchronously. That said, the objective of these 2 methods was to use as dummy long running process to demonstrate the scenario. The code runs just fine.

Comment: Is the actual long-running process going to be truly asynchronous? In that case I would suggest to replace the `Thread.Sleep(sleepDelay);` with `await Task.Delay(sleepDelay);`, to better represent your actual code's nature.

Comment: Yes, the actual long-running tasks are WebService calls that I was simulating using the Task.Sleep(). I do like your variant, and yes that is probably a better way to represent the task. Thanks @TheodorZoulias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your validation is already asynchronous, there's no need for `Task.Run`. You can just perform your validation asynchronously.

Also, consider using `Task.FromResult` to provide already-completed tasks if validation doesn't need to be run, and then you can retrieve all the results from `Task.WhenAll`. In general, asynchronous code is more functional in nature so it tends to work better when returning results instead of assigning results into variables as side effects.

Something like this:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
  bool validateParamA = true;
  var myFoo = new Foo();
  var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();
  tasks.Add(validateParamA ? myFoo.ValidateParamA(50) : Task.FromResult(false));
  tasks.Add(myFoo.ValidateParamB(30));

  bool[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  Console.WriteLine(results[0]);
  Console.WriteLine(results[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @stephen-cleary, this is definitely way more elegant. Very concise and easily readable.